# Adding a field when a model is read

Tags: php, lithium

Let's say I have a model named Reads that contains the following locked schema:

```
protected $_schema = array(
    '_id' => array('type' => 'id'),
    'name'  => array('type' => 'string', 'unique' => true),
    'read_by' => array('type' => 'string', 'array' => true)
);
```

The "read_by" field actually contains a list of users that have read a particular article.  When the model is loaded or ::find() is called, I want it to have another field called "read" that returns true if the currently logged in user's id is found in read_by and false if it is not.  Is this possible?  I've considered using the ::applyFilter method but am unsure where to go from there.

I'm using Mongo as my db.  Thanks.

**Edit**
As per Dave's answer below, the $result object set by $chain->next($self, $params, $chain); in the filter appears like the following:

```
lithium\data\collection\DocumentSet Object
(
    [_original:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_parent:protected] => 
[_pathKey:protected] => 
[_model:protected] => app\models\Reads
[_query:protected] => lithium\data\model\Query Object
    (
        [_map:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_entity:protected] => 
        [_data:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [_schema:protected] => 
        [_classes:protected] => Array
            (
                [schema] => lithium\data\Schema
            )

        [_fields:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [_alias:protected] => Array
            (
                [Reads] => 1
            )

        [_paths:protected] => Array
            (
                [Reads] => 
            )

        [_models:protected] => Array
            (
                [Reads] => app\models\Reads
            )

        [_autoConfig:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => map
            )

        [_initializers:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => model
                [1] => entity
                [2] => conditions
                [3] => having
                [4] => group
                [5] => order
                [6] => limit
                [7] => offset
                [8] => page
                [9] => data
                [10] => calculate
                [11] => schema
                [12] => comment
            )

        [_built:protected] => 1
        [_config:protected] => Array
            (
                [conditions] => Array
                    (
                        [feed_id] => Array
                            (
                                [$in] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => MongoId Object
                                            (
                                                [$id] => 51b79acbac53cfb51645ffa7
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [read_by] => Array
                            (
                                [$nin] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 51592dcc6d6d877c0a000002
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [order] => Array
                    (
                        [date_added] => DESC
                    )

                [limit] => 25
                [user] => 51592dcc6d6d877c0a000002
                [fields] => 
                [page] => 
                [with] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [type] => read
                [model] => app\models\Reads
                [mode] => 
                [source] => reads
                [alias] => Reads
                [having] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [group] => 
                [offset] => 
                [joins] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [data] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [whitelist] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [calculate] => 
                [schema] => 
                [comment] => 
                [map] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [relationships] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [_methodFilters:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[_result:protected] => lithium\data\source\mongo_db\Result Object
    (
        [_cache:protected] => 
        [_iterator:protected] => 0
        [_current:protected] => 
        [_started:protected] => 
        [_init:protected] => 
        [_valid:protected] => 
        [_key:protected] => 
        [_resource:protected] => MongoCursor Object
            (
            )

        [_autoConfig:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => resource
            )

        [_config:protected] => Array
            (
                [resource] => MongoCursor Object
                    (
                    )

                [init] => 1
            )

        [_methodFilters:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[_valid:protected] => 1
[_stats:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_started:protected] => 
[_exists:protected] => 
[_schema:protected] => 
[_autoConfig:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => model
        [1] => result
        [2] => query
        [3] => parent
        [4] => stats
        [5] => pathKey
        [6] => exists
        [7] => schema
    )

[_data:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_config:protected] => Array
    (
        [init] => 1
    )

[_methodFilters:protected] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

Comment: Having this as a property on the article model is far more convoluted than having something like `$user->read($article)`. I would devise you against populating such a property and rather go for calling a method.

Comment: $user->read I assume would be a helper method? I wanted to add the field to the Model because I'm firing that entire model as an ajax response.

Comment: The problem with patching it onto the entity itself becomes apparent when you start modifying that code and decides to save the entity without using schema whitelisting in the save call.
I prefer to patch the model in the controller in this case, and often by having a `Model#toPublic` method.

Comment: I've decided to make changes after loading the information. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your Reads model, you could define the `find` filter in the `__init()` function:

```
public static function __init() {
    static::applyFilter('find', function($self, $params, $chain) {
        //get the find result            
        $result = $chain->next($self, $params, $chain);
        //set default of 'read' field to false
        $read = false;
        //check if user is in 'read_by' array
        if (isset($params['user']) && isset($result->read_by)) {
            $read = in_array($params['user'], $result->read_by) ? true : false;
        });
        $result->read = $read;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then provide the matching User id or name, or whatever you're storing in the `read_by` array, when you run the find:

```
$reads = Reads::find('first', ['user' => 'username']);
```

(I'm using PHP 5.4 array syntax in these examples.)

Comment: Looks like the best solution, but $result->read_by (or $result->name and $result->_id for that matter) are always returning undefined error.

Comment: You sure you're not encountering a connections problem? How does your connections.php bootstrap configuration look?

Comment: The connection appears fine as Reads::find('all') returns exactly what I'd expect.